# how to completely disable the alert in 18.04 (not just the sound)?

Tags: 18.04

I was able to mute the alert sound in settings / sound effects and was able to turn the alert off in terminal, but I still get an alert freeze when scrolling in a file manager and getting to the end of the file list or reach the EOF in a text editor for example. When I get the alert the whole computer freezes for a couple of seconds including music or movies.

Comment: have you edited any settings? what is the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences visual-bell` ?

Comment: gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences visual-bell returns false. I surely edited tons of settings but I no longer remember which ones. Often my settings or system behavior change with updates so I have to correct that too. This includes the alert sound, I remember turning it off in the past (even though the freeze was still there) but after some update the sound came back again